Can I install standpipe traps tight against wall in series?
I am fitting a kitchen on a self fitout (shell built) and need knowledge on how to connect a dishwasher and washing machine to the grey waste pipe coming from sink. The appliances are too far to fit their drain pipes into fittings under the sink.
A plumber suggested using standpipes and putting the outflow pipe from the appliances in to these. He said this will prevent traps being drawn. Is this correct, and can I add and additional bend after the standpipes to face them downwards, as I need to put the standpipes above the main waste pipe, due to space? The pipe eventually drops in to a gully trap outside.


Is your concern because you have no venting?

If you add that downwards bend after the P trap you're making an S trap, you need to add venting or an AAV for the trap to function properly.

OK great thanks, I will look in to the AAV.

Thanks for the steer, appreciated.
